# Python setuptools get IOError not a directory for json file

Tags: python, json, setuptools

I am learning to write the setup.py for a python package that I am developing. I have a couple of json and yaml files in this package and in the setup.py file I added

```
    package_data={"tiny.core": ["*.json"],
                  "tiny.vasp_io": ["*.yaml"]},
```

I also added the following info in the MANIFEST.in file:

```
include *.rst requirements*.txt
recursive-include tiny *.py *.json *.yaml
```

and the following in the setup.cfg file

```
[aliases]
release = register sdist bdist_wheel upload
```

Then I did `python setup.py install` and everything looked fine. But when I ran my package, I got `IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory` for a json file in the egg. However, when I unzipped the egg folder, the json was in there. If I deleted the egg file, everything went back to normal again. I am pretty new to setuptools. Any ideas why this is happening? I also noticed that some other python modules have egg-link file, but I don't have that. Is that the reason here?
The repository takes this kind of shape:

```
/tiny
- .git/
- setup.py
- setup.cfg
- requirements.txt
- MANIFEST.in
- README.rst
- tiny
    - __init__.py
    - core
        - __init__.py
        - json_files.json
        - yaml_files.yaml
        - some_script.py
    - cli
        - __init__.py
        - cli.py
        - some_script.py
```

It seems if I use `python setup.py develop`, I won't get the error. Not really sure why.

Comment: What does the directory structure of your project look like?

Comment: @jwodder: I added the shape of my repository. Thanks